# "Validation failed for one or more entities. ERROR

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating web API to save the uploaded file in my local storage. When I testing my code it gives an error as  ExceptionMessage": "Validation failed for one or more entities. See EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Can anyone help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Controller(FileUploadController)

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using VantageCore.BL;
namespace VantageCoreApi.Controllers.Api
{
    public class FileUploadController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FileUpload")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile(string FileName, int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> ids = new List<string>();
                var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                var referenceId = FileName.Split('_')[0];
                foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
                {
                    Guid guid;
                    ids.Add(Guid.TryParse(await new FileUploadMgt().ReceiveFile(file, FileName, Id), out guid) ? FileName : "Error");
                }
                return Ok(ids);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }
        public string SaveFile(byte[] File, string path)
        {
            string Result = "";
            try
            {
                //LOCAL SERVER PATH
                var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(@"F:\Testfolder" + path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));

                fs.Write(File);
                fs.Close();
                Result = path;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Result = ee.ToString();
            }
            return Result;

        }

    }
}
```

BL (FileUplodMgt.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using VantageCore.Entity.Model;
using File = VantageCore.Entity.Model.File;

namespace VantageCore.BL
{
    public class FileUploadMgt
    {
        public async Task<string> ReceiveFile(HttpContent receivedFile, string receivedFileName, int Id)
        {

            if (receivedFile != null)
            {
                var fileId = Guid.NewGuid();
                using (var c = new DBEntities())
                {
                    NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
                    string folder = appSettings["TestPath"];
                    var fileName = fileId.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(receivedFileName).ToLower();
                    var file = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
                    bool exists = Directory.Exists(folder);
                    if (!exists) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                    using (var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        fs.Write(await receivedFile.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
                    }
                    string extention = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    receivedFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(receivedFileName).Length <= 32
                        ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(receivedFileName)
                        : Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(receivedFileName).Substring(0, 31) + "~";

                    var newFile = new File
                    {
                        Uid = fileId,
                        FileExtention = extention,
                        FileName = receivedFileName,
                        FileSize = (int)(receivedFile.Headers.ContentLength / 1024),
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                    };
                    c.Files.Add(newFile);
                    c.SaveChanges();
                }
                return fileId.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error,Invalid file Or file size exceeded";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your project a .net core project or asp.net project ? I can't reach await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);  in my .net core project

Comment: asp.net web API

Comment: I think the error  is related with c.SaveChanges(); you'd better share your entity and database,also ,you could try as  below to see the detail of the error

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below to observe the error message  when you debug and share it；

```
                try
                {
                    c.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    
                }
```